# Symfony cannot open any route but '/'

Tags: symfony, routes, http-status-code-404, controllers, php-7.1

I have the following setup:

```
OS: Debian GNU/Linux 9.1 (stretch)
Webserver: Apache/2.4.25 (Debian)
PHP: PHP 7.1.7-1+ubuntu17.10.1+deb.sury.org+1 (cli)
Symfony: Symfony 3.3.6
```

I've a fresh install of symfony running. I created a simple custom bundle.
The problem is I can only access the '/' route in a controller(s). the other routes reslts in a `404`.

So I tried deleting cache with:

```
console cache:clear 
console cache:clear --env=prod
console cache:clear --env=dev
```

This does not help. I also renewed/dumped the composer autoload files again.

I know symfony can see my the other routes, I can check it by running:
`console debug:router`

output:

```
  index                      ANY      ANY      ANY    /                                  
  test_action                ANY      ANY      ANY    /test
```

routing.yml:

```
...
index:
    path: /
    defaults: { _controller: MyAppBundle:Default:index }

test_action:
    path: /test
    defaults: { _controller: MyAppBundle:Application:test }
...
```

vhost: (directory part)

```
...

     <Directory /var/www/myproject/web>
          Options +FollowSymLinks
          Order allow,deny
          Allow from all
          Require all granted
     </Directory>

...
```

.htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
    Require all denied
</IfModule>
<IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
</IfModule>
```

I made sure that the rewrite module was enabled by running `a2enmod rewrite` and reloaded the server.

So the problem is I can't access any other route than '/' from the 'MyAppBundle:DefaultController' controller. Even if I define more routes inside the `DefaultController` I can't access those. all results in a '404' error.

I also tried switching to `app_dev.php` instead of `app.php` to see more debug information. But the profiler could not load (I got the same error, when i try to open the profiler)

Can somebody give me some advise on how to fix the routing/404 problems?

Comment: is http://yourhost.com/app_dev.php/ working?

Comment: Could you post your controller?